# How to connect my API to WSO2 API manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Below you can my wso2 EI  6.6.0 server configuration file.
[image]

And below the meta data configuration file content

```
key: "schoolApi-1.0.0"
name : "schoolApi"
displayName : "schoolApi"
description: "Sample API"
version: "1.0.0"
serviceUrl: "https://{MI_HOST}:{MI_PORT}/school"
definitionType: "OAS3"
securityType: "BASIC"
mutualSSLEnabled: false
apiId : "null"
```

I tried to connect my API to WSO2 API manager, But Its not showing in API Manager services.
[image]

Can anyone help me to solve this issue.

Comment: What's your APIM version and MI version? This feature is only supported in APIM/MI 4.x versions

Comment: I am using  wso2am-4.1.0 and wso2ei-6.6.0

Comment: This feature is not available in wso2ei. You need to use MI 4.x version. Since you use wso2am-4.1.0, it's better to use wso2mi-4.1.0.

Answer (score 2):

The service catalog feature is only available in APIM/MI v4.x versions. You cannot use EI 6.6.0 for the service catalog.

You can use EI 6.6.0 with API Manager 4.1.0 without the service catalog. You can deploy the integrations in EI and then provide the EI endpoint to the API in the API Manager.